# Unable to save data to Parse.com cloud service

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to save a file in "Parse.com" in my android application.However,I am being pestered by the following error

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class java.io.File
```

Below mentioned is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "nNDrIDPB8evzutqXnMkLNwV5l0yKm6RHQDshJhLN", "bkIb6fI9RWgezwulCHismlNUeYBz9sNxFaLxf8NB");
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\rishii\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Introduction\\file_input9.txt");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        fileInputStream.read(fileContent);
        ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(fileContent);
        ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("file_content!");
        dataObject.put("file",parseFile);
        dataObject.saveInBackground();
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am quite sure that the file path that i have given is correct.Below mentioned is my stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rishii.introduction/com.example.rishii.introduction.Main_activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class java.io.File
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class java.io.File
        at com.parse.ParseObject.performPut(ParseObject.java:3152)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:3139)
        at com.example.rishii.introduction.Main_activity.onCreate(Main_activity.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Any Suggestions are helpful!!!

Comment: As an advice for future questions: you shouldn't post your Parse access tokens on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @fixmycode Thanks!!will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android you can not directly import files from your local system.

You ahve to first save it to sdacrd or copy that text file to raw folder in your android porject.

Then you can save it to anyhwhere usign appropriate apis.

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\rishii\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Introduction\\file_input9.txt
```

This line is causing problem.